# How do I associate a C# object with a Unity gameobject?

Tags: c#, oop, object, unity-game-engine

I understand that Unity uses C# scripts in a component based way, but that doesn't work well enough in a lot of cases.

Heres an example: Say I have a turret class and a lazer class. They both inherit from an IShootable interface which implements a Shoot() method. I want to loop through all the IShootable objects in the scene and call Shoot(). Sounds simple enough but I don't necessarily want to add these scripts as components to gameobjects, but rather instantiate them the traditional C# way: Turret t1 = new Turret();

Basically, when I instantiate the C# object, I want to instantiate a unity gameobject and treat it nearly identically.

Im fairly amateur and I know theres no perfect answer to this. I just want a consistent way to handle this confusion and make it less messy.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Unless you are writing a text based adventure game the turrets have to shoot from somewhere? Why not have the turret be a component of that object shooting. However there is nothing wrong with your plan other than because you are no longer using the component system it is your resposability to keep track of all the IShootable objects yourself in a `List<IShootable>` somewhere (just like you would in normal C#) and foreach over that master list and call shoot.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. You're probably right, there is no reason not to use Unity's component system. Perhaps the engine just doesn't suit my style(?)

Comment: "Basically, when I instantiate the C# object, I want to instantiate a unity gameobject and treat it nearly identically."  this is completely meaningless. to instantiate a game object, instantiate a game object.

Comment: It may not "suit one's style" but there's no possible other way that an ECS with behaviors  attached to the physical objects .. can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an object to exist in the scene, then it *must* be a GameObject. There are no alternatives.

Now, its perfectly find to have your Turret and Laser objects *not* inherit from MonoBehaviour, but they'd have to be associated with something that *is* in the scene, somehow. And the only thing that exists in the scene are GameObjects.

- Option A: Make a MonoBehaviour script that has Turret and/or Laser as properties of that behavior script. Loop over all game objects in the scene and get their MB component and call Shoot() on that, which calls Shoot() for its encapsulated Turret or Laser object.
- Option B: Make your Turret and Laser scripts instantiate and store a reference to their associated GameObject. I do this, after a fashion, in one of the games I'm working on now.

Comment: With option B, how could we obtain the script from the gameobject? For example, with option A, we could use GetComponent<>() to obtain. Is it possible with option B?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Try `gameObject.GetComponent<SCRIPTCLASSNAME>();`

Comment: *"Make your Turret and Laser scripts .. store a reference to their associated GameObject."*  this is an utterly, utterly, utterly bizarre idea!  if you're a component, the game object you are on is .gameObject.  I guess, if you "don't like typing" .gameObject, but you want type, say, .banana or .moscow , you could use a property, or perhaps a preprocessor or such, to avoid typing .gameObject.

Answer (score -1):

I'll venture to assume that you are talking about an observer pattern.
Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx
and using Unity3d action and delegates:
Link: https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/input-actions-and-delegate-pattern
or using Unity3d Evetns.
I do not have enough reputation to insert another link, but you can find a tutorial on Unity's site